# Create new variables from format values

Tags: sas

**What i want to do:** I need to create a new variables for each value labels of a variable and do some recoding. I have all the value labels output from a SPSS file (see sample).

**Sample:**

```
proc format; library = library ;
   value SEXF
      1 = 'Homme'  
      2 = 'Femme' ;
   value FUMERT1F
      0 = 'Non'  
      1 = 'Oui , occasionnellement'  
      2 = 'Oui , régulièrement'  
      3 = 'Non mais j''ai déjà fumé' ;
   value ... (many more with different amount of levels)
```

The new variable name would be the actual one without F and with underscore+level (example: FUMERT1F level 0 would become FUMERT1_0).

After that i need to recode the variables on this pattern:

```
data ds; set ds;
    FUMERT1_0=0;
    if FUMERT1=0 then FUMERT1_0=1;

    FUMERT1_1=0;
    if FUMERT1=1 then FUMERT1_1=1;

    FUMERT1_2=0;
    if FUMERT1=2 then FUMERT1_2=1;

    FUMERT1_3=0;
    if FUMERT1=3 then FUMERT1_3=1;
run;
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

EDIT: Both answers from Joe and the one of data_null_ are working but stackoverflow won't let me pin more than one right answer.

Comment: You don't explain how the value labels are used?  Seems like you are making dummies and SAS has PROCs for that.

Comment: I'm using them in a proc reg but i might be changing my method for a proc surveyreg using class.

Comment: Yes this is the same thing the CLASS statement does only the CLASS statement does it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to add an _ underscore to the end of each name.  It looks like there is not option for PROC TRANSREG to put an underscore between the variable name and the value of the class variable so we can just do a temporary rename.  Create rename name=newname pairs to rename class variable to end in underscore and to rename them back.  CAT functions and SQL into macro variables.

```
data have;
   call streaminit(1234);
   do caseID = 1 to 1e4;
      fumert1 = rand('table',.2,.2,.2) - 1;
      sex = first(substrn('MF',rand('table',.5),1));
      output;
      end;
   stop;
   run;
%let class=sex fumert1;
proc transpose data=have(obs=0) out=vnames;
   var &class;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc sql noprint;
   select catx('=',_name_,cats(_name_,'_')), catx('=',cats(_name_,'_'),_name_), cats(_name_,'_')
      into :rename1 separated by ' ', :rename2 separated by ' ', :class2 separated by ' '
      from vnames;
   quit;
%put NOTE: &=rename1;
%put NOTE: &=rename2;
%put NOTE: &=class2;
proc transreg data=have(rename=(&rename1));
   model class(&class2 / zero=none);
   id caseid;
   output out=design(drop=_: inter: rename=(&rename2)) design;
   run;
%put NOTE: _TRGIND(&_trgindn)=&_trgind;
```

[image]

---

First try:
Looking at the code you supplied and the output from Joe's I don't really understand the need for the formats.  It looks to me like you just want to create dummies for a list of class variables.  That can be done with TRANSREG.

```
data have;
   call streaminit(1234);
   do caseID = 1 to 1e4;
      fumert1 = rand('table',.2,.2,.2) - 1;
      sex = first(substrn('MF',rand('table',.5),1));
      output;
      end;
   stop;
   run;

proc transreg data=have;
   model class(sex fumert1 / zero=none);
   id caseid;
   output out=design(drop=_: inter:) design;
   run;
proc contents;
   run;
proc print data=design(obs=40);
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: I figured SAS had a proc for that, but have never used it and don't remember seeing this on the 'L before - looks good!

Comment: Works well! One thing only, is it possible to add the underscore between the variable name and the category number?

Comment: @Joe If my search of the archive is correct PROC TRANSREG has not been mentioned in 10 years.

Comment: @Oligg I think so.  I will look.  I was thinking the ideal output would name the the variables using the value and create labels using the formatted values.

Comment: The majority of my variables already ends with a number and it could get confusing but i can deal with it if it's not possible (and/or easy) ;)

Comment: Interestingly there is a SEP option to create the variable label that produces the desired label but not variable name.  I will modify my answer to make with a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

One good alternative to your code is to use `proc transpose`.  It won't get you 0's in the non-1 cells, but those are easy enough to get.  It does have the disadvantage that it makes it harder to get your variables in a particular order.

Basically, transpose once to vertical, then transpose back using the old variable name concatenated to the variable value as the new variable name.  Hat tip to Data *null* for showing this feature in a recent SAS-L post.  If your version of SAS doesn't support concatenation in PROC TRANSPOSE, do it in the data step beforehand.

I show using `PROC EXPAND` to then set the missings to 0, but you can do this in a data step as well if you don't have ETS or if `PROC EXPAND` is too slow.  There are other ways to do this - including setting up the dataset with 0s pre-proc-transpose - and if you have a complicated scenario where that would be needed, this might make a good separate question.

```
data have;
  do caseID = 1 to 1e4;
    fumert1 = rand('Binomial',.3,3);
    sex = rand('Binomial',.5,1)+1;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want_pre;
  by caseID;
  var fumert1 sex;
  copy fumert1 sex;
run;

data want_pre_t;
  set want_pre;
  x=1;  *dummy variable;
run;

proc transpose data=want_pre_t out=want delim=_;
  by caseID;
  var x;
  id _name_ col1;
  copy fumert1 sex;
run;

proc expand data=want out=want_e method=none;
convert _numeric_ /transformin=(setmiss 0);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! It does the job for what i want :)
My idea was more oriented on looping on values set inside a format (is that even possible?) but as yours works like a charm i'll keep that.

Comment: You can't directly get at the values of the format in the data step, no.  There are another five or six ways to do this - figured 2 was enough :) - but I don't think you can do this solely in a data step without contortions of epic size.  I suppose you could loop over all numbers and see if the format assigns them a value... but that seems ... complex.

Answer (score 1):

For this method, you need to use two concepts: the `cntlout` dataset from `proc format`, and code generation.  This method will likely be faster than the other option I presented (as it passes through the data only once), but it does rely on the variable name <-> format relationship being straightforward.  If it's not, a slightly more complex variation will be required; you should post to that effect, and this can be modified.

First, the `cntlout` option in `proc format` makes a dataset of the contents of the format catalog.  This is not the only way to do this, but it's a very easy one.  Specify the appropriate libname as you would when you create a format, but instead of making one, it will dump the dataset out, and you can use it for other purposes.

Second, we create a macro that performs your action one time (creating a variable with the name_value name and then assigning it to the appropriate value) and then use `proc sql` to make a bunch of calls to that macro, once for each row in your `cntlout` dataset.  Note - you may need a `where` clause here, or some other modifications, if your format library includes formats for variables that aren't in your dataset - or if it doesn't have the nice neat relationship your example does.  Then we just make those calls in a data step.

```
*Set up formats and dataset;
proc format;
   value SEXF
      1 = 'Homme'  
      2 = 'Femme' ;
   value FUMERT1F
      0 = 'Non'  
      1 = 'Oui , occasionnellement'  
      2 = 'Oui , régulièrement'  
      3 = 'Non mais j''ai déjà fumé' ;
 quit;


data have;
  do caseID = 1 to 1e4;
    fumert1 = rand('Binomial',.3,3);
    sex = rand('Binomial',.5,1)+1;
    output;
  end;
run;

*Dump formats into table;
proc format cntlout=formats;
quit;

*Macro that does the above assignment once;
%macro spread_var(var=, val=);
  &var._&val.= (&var.=&val.);  *result of boolean expression is 1 or 0 (T=1 F=0);
%mend spread_var;

*make the list.  May want NOPRINT option here as it will make a lot of calls in your output window otherwise, but I like to see them as output.;
proc sql;
  select cats('%spread_var(var=',substr(fmtname,1,length(Fmtname)-1),',val=',start,')')
    into :spreadlist separated by ' '
    from formats;
quit;


*Actually use the macro call list generated above;
data want;
  set have;
  &spreadlist.;
run;
```

Comment: I am blocked on the proc format cntlout. How can i give only one specific format (variable) to the statement instead of all my formats? Thanks for helping :)

Comment: `select` statement will get you there, though in the example you give I would assume you want all formats - or, at least you want all of the formats that qualify for the variables on a particular dataset.  You don't want to do just one at a time, for sure.  I suspect more likely you would want to join the `cntlout` result with `dictionary.columns` or with a `proc contents` output dataset to find what formats you actually want.

Comment: I need to run them all at once and also to feed a single variable name in a macro for another purpose (unless that is really slow)

Comment: data_null_ solutions works for my macro purpose so there is no need to go through that trouble